# How to fix "Run time error "1004" reference is not valid" in excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA code in Office 365 for goal seeking. I have recorded the code using goal seek formula for a single cell. How can I make it functionable for a specific range?

```
Sub ddpdio()
'
' ddpdio Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Z
'
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("J6").GoalSeek Goal:=5.5, ChangingCell:=Range("H6")
    Range("H19").Select
End Sub
```

Here, I can get the required value in cell `J6` changing the cell `H6`. But I need to run the VBA for the range `J6:J18` by changing the value of the range `H6:H18`. But if I replace `J6` by `J6:J18` and `H6` by `H6:H18`, I am getting reference error message.

Comment: `GoalSeek` changes **one** cell to achieve a goal in **one** cell. If you have several instances of this, write a loop. If you have a more complex problem, use the solver.

Comment: Thanks, @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I am trying myself actually. But I'm not a pro coder. However, ur suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: I added a solution with a loop. If the J cells depends on several H cells, it's more difficult and you need the solver (which can handle optimization in several dimensions, whereas GoalSeek can only explore one dimension).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each cell in column J depends only on one cell incolumn H, then you can do a loop to achieve this, running one GoalSeek in each loop (here I set the goal as `I`, but it could be anything):

```
Sub Test()
    Dim I As Long
    For I = 6 To 18
        Cells(I, 10).GoalSeek Goal:=I, ChangingCell:=Cells(I, 8)
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your effort and time. But it gets the result 6 to 16 accordingly whereas I was looking for 6 in all the cells. However, i have got a solution. Have a look below please. BTW, your DP is really nice and I am also a cat lover :)

Comment: Sorry I am banned to make answer :|

Comment: @ShazzadKabir Change `Goal:=I` to anything you want. For instance `Goal:=6` if you want `6` everywhere.

Comment: It is working perfectly. Thanks again. Could you please suggest some guideline for a newbie VBA learner to learn effectively? Again thanks Buddy.

Comment: @ShazzadKabir I learned mostly by recoding macros and looking at the code + googling (there are many nices sites on Excel) + reading carefully the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/language-reference), especially for class methods and properties. See also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/d5418146-0bd2-45eb-9c7a-fd9502722c74) and [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40326).

Comment: thanks for your valuable note. I will surely follow it.

Comment: @ShazzadKabir There is a typo: by reco**r**ding macros. It's an extremely useful feature of Excel: almost everything you do in Excel can be automated in VBA, and you will find the exact syntax by recording a macro while you do it (often it can be simplified, but you will learn this later).